# C# ListView move to next object when i click button

Tags: c#, listview, listviewitem

I have a little problem. When I click the button, I want the ListView to move to the next object. Also, when it moves to the new object, it needs to get the address of the new object.

The program will switch to the new picture in the ListView every time the save button is clicked.

[image]

button click codes:

```
                    
int next=Convert.ToInt32(listView1.FocusedItem.Index) + 1;
                    
listView1.Items[next].Selected = true;

degisken = secilen.SubItems[sayac].Text;
```

listbox1 SelectedIndexChanged codes:

```
private void listView1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    secilen = listView1.FocusedItem;
            
    degisken = secilen.SubItems[sayac].Text;

    pictureBox1.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;

    string alan = degisken;
    pictureBox1.ImageLocation = yol + "/" + alan;
}
```

The program will switch to the new picture in the listview every time the save button is clicked.

Comment: What buttons are there? Do you want the action to happen on the Save button? What is the other button? Are you sure that the code in under the correct button?

Comment: Yes , code inside is save button

Comment: What is not working?

Comment: When I press the save button, it does not move to the next listView1 item.